# When does .m2 folder gets created while using gradle with Java

Tags: java, maven, build.gradle

I am currently working on Java with gralde where the build.properties file looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

//Artifactory Central Repository
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'abc'
            credentials {
                username = ""
                password = ""
            }
```

I am totally new to this framework and have the following questions:

1. Here, I understand that the dependencies are getting downloaded from the maven repository. And wondering if .m2 folder will be created when I execute this. or will this work without creating .m2 local repo. 
   I read that local repo is needed only for maven, not grade.
   So, in this case where Gradle is used to access maven repo to download dependencies, is .m2 folder needed.
2. When does this .m2 folder gets created?
3. After the Gradle build is successful, I did check in my {user home} but there are no .m2 created
4. I did try getting info from Google but didn't get any clarity on this.
   confused on how does Gradle uses .m2 while building its project.